# How to filter the same sub-array from two-dimensional array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

Suppose there are multiple sub-arrays with disordered integer elements, for example:

`[[1, 2], [2, 1], [3, 2, 2], [2], [2, 1, 3], [2, 2, 3]]`

I want to sort elements in every subarray and remove duplicates. So, after processing those data, the result should be the following:

`[[1, 2], [2, 2, 3], [2], [1, 2, 3]]`

How can I do it efficiently in JavaScript?

Comment: so you want to reduce the arrays to only unique ones?

Comment: How are you doing the sort/filtering now?

Answer (score 2):

If your data is actually arrays of integers, you could do it like this

```
// ES6
let data = [[1, 2], [2, 1], [3, 2, 2], [2], [2, 1, 3], [2, 2, 3]];

// non-mutating sort function
function sort(x) { let y = x.slice(0); y.sort(); return y; }

let final = data.map(x => JSON.stringify(sort(x))).reduce((res, x) =>
  res.indexOf(x) === -1 ? res.concat(x) : res
, []).map(JSON.parse);

console.log(data);
console.log(final);

// [[1,2],[2,1],[3,2,2],[2],[2,1,3],[2,2,3]]
// [[1,2],[2,2,3],[2],[1,2,3]]
```

Notice that my solution does **not** mutate your input `data` unnecessarily (like the other solutions provided here)

If you need the ES5 code, here you go

```
// ES5
var data = [[1, 2], [2, 1], [3, 2, 2], [2], [2, 1, 3], [2, 2, 3]];

// non-mutating sort function
function sort(x) {
  var y = x.slice(0);y.sort();return y;
}

var final = data.map(function (x) {
  return JSON.stringify(sort(x));
}).reduce(function (res, x) {
  return res.indexOf(x) === -1 ? res.concat(x) : res;
}, []).map(JSON.parse);

console.log(data);
console.log(final);

// [[1,2],[2,1],[3,2,2],[2],[2,1,3],[2,2,3]]
// [[1,2],[2,2,3],[2],[1,2,3]]
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try this: first sort them then remove the duplicates.

```js
var x=[[1, 2], [2, 1], [3, 2, 2], [2], [2, 1, 3], [2, 2, 3]];
     for(i in x){
        x[i].sort();
    }
     b = uniqBy(x, JSON.stringify)
        document.getElementById("data").innerHTML=JSON.stringify(b);

    function uniqBy(a, key) {
        var seen = {};
        return a.filter(function(item) {
            var k = key(item);
            return seen.hasOwnProperty(k) ? false : (seen[k] = true);
        })
    }
```

```html
<div id="data"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

First, we need to sort your subarrays out. It is easy, because there is a built-in JavaScript function `sort()`:

```js
var arr = [[1, 2], [2, 1], [3, 2, 2], [2], [2, 1, 3], [2, 2, 3]];

arr.forEach(function(subarr) {
  subarr.sort();
});

document.body.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(arr);
```

Now, we need to remove duplicates. There are two ways to do this - proper and hacky. I will describe the hacky one. To compare two arrays, you can simply compare their string representations:

```js
var arr = [[1, 2], [2, 1], [3, 2, 2], [2], [2, 1, 3], [2, 2, 3]];

arr.forEach(function(subarr) {
  subarr.sort();
});

var arrStrings = [];

arr = arr.filter(function(subarr) {
  var stringified = JSON.stringify(subarr); // or simply .toString()
  if (arrStrings.indexOf(stringified) === -1)
  {
    arrStrings.push(stringified);
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
});

document.body.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(arr);
```

There are many non-hacky and proper solutions to compare arrays, you can read [this StackOverflow article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7837456/how-to-compare-arrays-in-javascript) and choose the one you like.

Answer (score 1):

Let's add another solution into the mix

```js
var arr = [[1, 2], [2, 1], [3, 2, 2], [2], [2, 1, 3], [2, 2, 3]];
var temp = {};
var updated = arr.reduce(function(prev, arr){ 
  var adj = arr.slice(0).sort();
  if (!temp[adj.join(",")]) { 
    prev.push(adj);
    temp[adj.join(",")] = true;
  }
  return prev;
},[]);
console.log(JSON.stringify(updated));
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use this javascript:

```
var arr = [[1, 2], [2, 1], [3, 2, 2], [2], [2, 1, 3], [2, 2, 3]];

function sortArray(array) {
  var count = array.length;
  var sorted = array.sort();
  var equal = true;

  for (var i=0;i<count;i++) {
    if (array[i].length > 1)
      array[i].sort();
  }
  array.sort().sort();

  for (var i=0;i<count;i++) {
    if (array[i] && array[i+1]) {
      for (var j=0, len=array[i].length; j<len; j++) {
        if (array[i][j] !== array[i+1][j])
          equal = false;
      }
      if (equal)
        array.splice(i,1);
      equal = true;
   }

  }

  console.log(array);
 }

 sortArray(arr);
```

Hope that helps!!